# Change model in jwt django REST

Tags: django, rest, authentication, jwt

I want to use jwt for authentication, but I don't want use User model.
How can I do this.
I know, I should override JSONWebTokenSerializer and set obj in jwt_payload_handler, but display this error message:

```
object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: What do you want to use instead of User Model?

Comment: my frontend is a device, and I want to authenticate this device via serial number